# How to detect if there any javascript alert box is opened on browser? if yes, How to close it using ruby and selenium

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium

While navigating from one page to another using selenium function, sometimes confirm box appears with ok and cancel option. So How to detect the box and dismiss that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to try/catch when switching to Alert window.

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new
alert = wait.until { page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert }
alert.accept # to accept alert
alert.dismiss # to dismiss alert
```

Hope it helps!